# Unambiguous alternative to “to consider sth. offensive”

Tags: phrase-requests

#### Main Question

> I consider [noun] [adjective].

usually means that I arrived at the conclusion that *[noun]* has the property described by *[adjective].* However, when the adjective is *offensive,* this phrase has adopted an additional meaning, namely

> I consider this statement offensive.

is often used to express that one is offended by the statement, which is not the same thing. For example not being Atlantean, I am not offended by the statement “All Atlanteans are mentally challenged and wear underpants on their head.”¹, but I still hold the opinion that it is offensive (or at least that it would be, if Atlantis were real).

With *to consider sth. offensive* being out of the game, what other concise construction can I use to express that I arrived at the conclusion that a statement is offensive – in a way that cannot be understood such that I express being offended by the statement? With other words: Which other, preferably verb-like phrase can I use to say that I literally consider something offensive?

---

<sup>¹ I am slightly offended by someone belonging to the same species at me uttering this statement, but that’s a different story.</sup>

#### Specific Example

This question arose in discussions about Stack Exchange moderation (which I cannot post here), where different interpretations of *finding sth. offensive* and *considering sth. offensive* lead to confusion. For example, a moderator could leave a comment on a post:

> I deleted the last sentence of your answer because I *consider it offensive.*

As moderators should be neutral and do not act from personal motivation, it is desirable for a moderator to avoid the impression that he is offended and thus personally concerned with the issue. Hence *to consider sth. offensive* is a suboptimal choice here. **I am looking for something to replace this.**

#### Other alternatives that don’t work

- > to find sth. offensive
  >   to regard sth. as offensive

  These have the same problem as *considering sth. offensive,* i.e., they are also used in the meaning of *to be offended.* I also consulted a thesaurus for possible synonyms of *consider, find,* and *regard* that could be used instead, but I found none.
- > to hold the opinion that sth. is offensive
  >   to arrive at the conclusion that sth. is offensive

  These express the right thing, but are comparably convoluted in my opinion.
- > to literally consider sth. offensive

  I cannot be certain that *literally* is understood as intended or that it is clear on what level I want to make things literal.

Comment: "a statement offends me" = "I hold the opinion that this statement is offensive". You can be offended by something that isn't an offense to you directly.

Comment: @Mitch: Dictionaries [[1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offend)], [[2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offend)] and I disagree with you. *Offended* implies some relevant emotional reaction. While some people may have such a reaction to something that isn’t a direct offense to them, I and certainly many others don’t.

Comment: Those two dictionaries agree with me. They don't specify that you are the subject of the offending statement. "That statement offends me" can be because it mentions underwear.

Comment: I'm curious about the motivation behind this distinction. Seems to me this would be either something that you want to take on as offensive to yourself or let it go. I suppose a stereotypical British response on some US show would be something along the lines of "offends my sensibilities"... but other than that, I don't know why this would even be an exercise worth adopting. I think life is too short to approach people about things that they do or say that might offend *somebody*.

Comment: @Mitch: They do not specify that you have to be the subject, right. But they also do not specify that if a statement is offensive (causing negative emotional response) to somebody, it is offensive (causing negative emotional response) to everybody who agrees with it being offensive. Also, if this were the case, we also would need to find a new word for negative emotional responses by offense.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks, this actually clarifies greatly... I probably would agree with Hot Licks on this. Isn't there a standards policy or something we all agree to when we sign up for this site, though? Couldn't you just say the post/statement "violates the usage policies for the site"? Just trying to make it sound as objective as possible.

Comment: I'm closevoting on the grounds that *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used*. That's because OP's cited context involves an ELU mod wishing to disambiguate between whether he thinks a comment is *objectively* offensive, or whether *he personally* finds it offensive. Although I'm not a mod, I'm sure it's part of their "rules of engagement" that they should not allow personal feeling to influence how they carry out their duties. So it's not a meaningful context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But surely there are many essentially identical situations where the only difference is that they don't have that as part of their "rules of engagement"; I think one can extract a meaningful context without too much effort.

Comment: @Brian: To the extent that there's a "meaningful answer" here, it's just that *It is/may be offensive* could in principle be an "objective" statement, whereas *I am offended* is inherently a subjective assessment. But that's a trivial observation, and everything else is effectively etiquette and/or writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: 1) This is not about an ELU mod (though it may as well happen to one). 2) Sure, moderators should be neutral, but that’s not something I can expect every readerd to understand as a premise of every statement I make. Actually, trying to adhere to this ideal of neutrality is what I explicitly gave as a motivation for making a neutral statement as described above. Moderator actions do not become neutral because it’s written down somewhere that they should be.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: The difference between an objective and a subjective assertion is clearly specified in my preceding comment (and it's trivial, so does not constitute a valid ELU question). I posted that comment along with my closevote to show that I could have chosen other reasons (i.e. - that it's *writing advice*).

Comment: Isn't 'I deleted the last sentence of your answer because I consider it offensive.' not impersonal enough because of the use of the _I_'s? // >  '... was deleted as being potentially offensive'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That’s close to one of the rejected alternatives I removed to focus the question (see the edit history for more). *Potentially offensive* can lead to all sorts of silly discussion; “was deleted as offensive” is too strong. At the end of the day, this is not about totally different sentences, then it would indeed be writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *The difference between an objective and a subjective assertion is clearly specified in my preceding comment (and it's trivial […]).* – So, what’s your trivial solution then? Saying “I consider this statement objectively offensive” or “I objectively consider this statement offensive” will certainly come over as arrogant and not help to deescalate things. — As for the writing advice: That example sentence in the second section is really just an example sentence. I do not ask for ways to rephrase that particular sentence.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: If you say ***I consider** [some assertion] [to be true/false]*, the utterance is *explicitly* subjective. Structurally, the "objective" version of the utterance would simply be *This assertion **is** true* (with no mention of this being simply *in the opinion of the speaker*). But we can reasonably suppose that *no* utterance is inherently offensive to *everyone*, so a truly objective assertion for your context would probably have to limit itself to *This statement **may cause** offence* or similar (otherwise you imply that everyone else shares your particular sensibilities).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *If you say* **I consider** [some assertion] [to be true/false], *the utterance is* explicitly *subjective.* – Sure, that’s exactly what I want to convey here and why I do not want to resort to plainly saying “this is offensive”. On the other hand, in this case, I could go one step further in terms of subjectiveness and say “this is offensive because it offends me”, which is what I explicitly do not want to do – my sensibilities are not of concern for this statement.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This statement **may cause** offence *or similar (otherwise you imply that everyone else shares your particular sensibilities)* – I fail to see the dichotomy here. My evaluation of offensiveness is by far not identical with my sensibilities (at least I hope so). If I say that “I have arrived at the conclusion that this statement is offensive.”, I do not see any implication about my sensibilities, yet I do not have to say something useless like *may cause offense* (which applies to a lot of statements that are harmless by any reasonable standards).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: This is essentially a matter of philosophy/epistemology, not the English language as such. To repeat myself - in the context of something like *offence* (which is effectively a [quale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia)) I think it's inherently subjective to suppose or assert that *anything* can be intrinsically offensive to *everybody*, regardless of whether you simply state that it ***is** offensive*, or explicitly point out that this is merely what you *think* (after due consideration, or as a knee-jerk reaction).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *it's inherently subjective to suppose or assert that* anything *can be intrinsically offensive to* everybody – Sure, but where do I even remotely say that I want to do this?

Comment: If 'potentially offensive' can lead to all sorts of 'silly' discussion, I can't see why 'offensive' can't also. These areas are highly open to opinion (hence your question).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Sure, silly discussions happen all the time, but *offensive* on its own is much less problematic. If you write *potentially offensive,* somebody comes along and says something along the lines of: “If it’s only potentially offensive, where is the problem? It’s not really offensive, so please undelete my post … racist.” Also, when somebody resorts to the defense that *offensive* is subjective, you can tell them that you were elected/appointed to make such judgements and they have to take it to Meta if they disagree.

Comment: What I'm saying is that M: 'I consider this statement offensive though I myself am not offended by it' is itself contentious. ELU has already discussed the scope / limitations of the label 'offensive', including how many people need to say they find a term / statement ... offensive before the descriptor becomes appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could distance yourself by making it an objective measurement or determination:

> I deleted the last sentence of your answer because I determined
>   it to be offensive.

Answer (score 3):

> I deleted the last sentence of your answer because it appeared to be offensive.

Avoiding mentioning yourself lifts the suspicion that you personally feel offended. At the same time, you mitigate a bit, not stating directly that the statement offends, but only that it has all the markings of an offensive statement.

Answer (score 2):

To sligltly reword "Somebody could be offended by this statment" :

"**Many will find this statement offensive**".

Comment: Doesn't this leave a lingering implication that you don't find it offensive, as though you'd merely prefer the statement not be uttered within earshot of someone who might be offended?

Comment: This has the same problems as [Kristina Lopez’s answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/299847/42471) in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of the confusion here is that the difference between "finding a statement offensive" and "being offended by a statement", while real, is so microscopic as to be in practice unimportant in almost any real-life context. To take your facetious example about Atlanteans, while you claim not to be offended by the pejorative description of Atlanteans but to still "find it offensive," I would argue that you are **actually offended**, not by the implication that you are a person who wears their underwear on their head, but by the knowledge that you are talking to a person who would utter such foolish statements, and that an Atlantean passing by may be seriously offended by the statement. The point is that you are still somewhat offended by the statement, but to a slightly lesser extent and for slightly different reasons.

In other words, "finding something offensive" is a kind of "being offended to the second order". **It still involves some measure of direct disapproval and taking offense**, not just the kind of indirect, neutral, unemotional kind of disapproval that you seem to be suggesting is (or should be) the interpretation of "I find this offensive" and that you claim you are trying to express.

To summarize, if indeed you wish to express a completely indirect, neutral kind of disapproval, I completely agree that "I find this offensive" isn't going to cut it. If you want to really remove all trace of ambiguity, I don't see any alternative to just spelling things out in complete detail, as in:

> In my opinion, this statement is very likely to offend a reasonable
>   Atlantean and a fair number of other reasonable people. I should emphasize that I
>   personally am not offended neither by its contents nor by the
>   likelihood that it will offend others.

This addresses the "unambiguously" part of your question, but that comes at the expense of the "briefly" requirement. Honestly, given the above analysis I don't see a way to achieve both goals at the same time.

Comment: While I agree that there seems to be a problem with distinguishing between *being offended* and *finding something offensive* (which was indeed one of the catalysers for the question), I do not think that this is due to the relevance of cases but due to natural language development. While I am “second-order offended” by stupid racial slurs and similar, there are statements which I totally agree with and yet would consider offensive, not utter in public and remove as a moderator.

Answer (score -2):

Consider using:

> I find that statement distasteful

You're asserting that in your judgement the statement is in poor taste without directly saying it is offensive to *you* specifically.

Context may make this more or less usable though. Distaste is not fully synonymous with offence, but there is significant overlap.

Comment: This, in my opinion, comes right out and states that you find the statement offensive because is there really any other way to feel about something one finds personally distasteful than "offensive"?  A bag of doggy doo-doo is distasteful and you'd be lying if you said you were not also offended (put-off, repulsed) if offered said bad of doggy doo-doo. :-)

Comment: Do you consider distasteful and offensive to mean the same thing? If not, could you clarify what difference you think they have? To me there's a personal delineation between (impersonal) distaste and (personal) offence.

Comment: @KristinaLopez What if someone told a sexist or racist joke to a white man for example. The man may not feel offended (as the joke did not sleight *his* person) but would find it distasteful as it is still a joke in poor taste.